# How can I make my counter look less fake?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this bit of code to display the number of users on a site.
My customer is complaining it looks fake. Any suggestions?

```
    var visitors = 187584;
    var updateVisitors = function()
        {
            visitors++;

            var vs = visitors.toString(), 
                 i = Math.floor(vs.length / 3),
                 l = vs.length % 3;
            while (i-->0) if (!(l==0&&i==0))
                vs = vs.slice(0,i*3+l)
                   + ',' 
                   + vs.slice(i*3+l);
            $('#count').text(vs);
            setTimeout(updateVisitors, Math.random()*2000);
        };

    setTimeout(updateVisitors, Math.random()*2000);
```

**Edited:**

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/4268/reachdevs2.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/4268/reachdevs2.png)
[Screenshot-Advertise - Stack Overflow - Chromium http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8083/screenshotadvertisestac.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8083/screenshotadvertisestac.png)

http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx

Comment: Did your customer tell you what a non-fake counter looked like?

Comment: Making it real is probably the best solution.

Comment: Is this homework, Eddy!?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: It was not really my code. Got some great answers though. (see edit)

Comment: it _is_ fake. what do you expect?

Comment: Fake counters are like splash screens from the 90s. A longer splash screen equated to better programs with more functionality. Not anymore :)

Comment: Brilliant! I love that it uses the `-->` operator!

Comment: Gold!  A+ Would upvote again.

Comment: I was looking at the page in question yesterday made me laugh soon as I read the code. <3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everyone knows JS counters are fake, don't bother trying to make it look "less fake", bother making a real one.

If you don't have enough visitors to show around, just don't use a counter, they're so 90's.

Comment: +1 for that last comment. No-one give a rats backside how many people visit your site. Just make it good, word will spread, people will link to you and Google will bump you up in its rankings. Having a site tell us how popular it is is no different to a slick-oil used car dealer telling us how trustworthy they are.

Answer (score 9):

Warning: Attempted Humour

Did he ask for a giant splash page to go along with the fake real-time visitor counter? How about some nice "Netscape Now!" button logos and blinking text? Here are some really cool "under construction" animated gifs you can use too.

http://www.animatedgif.net/underconstruction/construction.shtml

-Oisin

Comment: Don't forget the autoplaying MIDI.

Comment: You know, Macromedia has this amazing new thing called Flash. You can do awesome animations and multimedia stuff with it. Maybe a really long intro instead of a splash page? - Ok that's enough, I'm getting sick ...

Comment: http://wonder-tonic.com/geocitiesizer/content.php?theme=1&music=3&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870794/how-can-i-make-my-counter-look-less-fake :)

Comment: @Steve, myspace still has those and the midis too :P

Comment: Hahaha, alex, that is amazing. Wow.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing it looks fake because every time you load the page it starts at the same number and counts upwards?

Take a look at the javascript that tells you how many megabytes of email storage you get with a Gmail account.  I think it bases the starting number on the date/time, so that if you load a page, watch it count up, and then load it again, it won't reload with a smaller number.

Be honest though... it **is** fake right?  You aren't showing precisely how many users there are and updating it live as new users create accounts.  The goal then is to make sure it is somewhat close to reality.  Hopefully the rate at which the number increases in your script is based on past new-user subscription rates.

Answer (score 0):

make the interval parameter of the setInterval random as well ... it will look more real as it will randomly increment the random numbers :)